# Sending Screen using Delphi (Implementing VNC client / Server)

Tags: delphi, vnc

Been reading some Documentation for Indy some few weeks back. Using Indy i have been able to implement client and server program for simple programs hence i wanted to test myself for a VNC program like teamviewer, started out using Indy and i did like the topic well than using Raw winsock , Indy did help me, but I do have one issue i want to trade out. 
I am coding something like my own teamviewer which requires client and server now i want to get the screenshot from the server and send to client

on client side i do something that Looks like this  to connect

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
IdTCPServer1:=TIdTCPServer.Create(nil);
IdTCPServer1.DefaultPort:=50000;
IdTCPServer1.OnExecute:=IdTCPServer1Execute;
IdTCPServer1.Active:=true;
end;
```

Now the onExecute would look like this to grab the screenshot and send vis Indy (Winsock)

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
mem_dc : HDC;
bmp : TBitmap;
_bm : BITMAP;
w, h : Integer;
dimensions : Integer;
begin
    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    GetObject (bm, sizeof (BITMAP), @_bm);
    w := _bm.bmWidth;
    h := _bm.bmHeight;
    bmp.Height := h;
    bmp.Width := w;
    mem_dc := CreateCompatibleDC (bmp.Canvas.Handle);
    SelectObject (mem_dc, bm);
    BitBlt (bmp.Canvas.Handle,0, 0, w, h, mem_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    Canvas.Draw (0, 0, bmp);
    DeleteObject (mem_dc);
    bmp.Free;

    //Send Dimensions vis Indy here 
    dimensions := w * h / 4;
    while True do
    begin
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(dimensions);
        // and do same for Pixels
    end;
end.
```

Since i am new to something like this, do i just get the width and height and send or do i have to send them separately with something like this :

```
procedure TForm1.IdTCPServer1Execute(AContext: TIdContext);
var
mem_dc : HDC;
bmp : TBitmap;
_bm : BITMAP;
w, h : Integer;
begin
    bmp := TBitmap.Create;
    GetObject (bm, sizeof (BITMAP), @_bm);
    w := _bm.bmWidth;
    h := _bm.bmHeight;
    bmp.Height := h;
    bmp.Width := w;
    mem_dc := CreateCompatibleDC (bmp.Canvas.Handle);
    SelectObject (mem_dc, bm);
    BitBlt (bmp.Canvas.Handle,0, 0, w, h, mem_dc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    Canvas.Draw (0, 0, bmp);
    DeleteObject (mem_dc);
    bmp.Free;

    //Send Dimensions vis Indy here 
    dimensions := w * h;
    while True do
    begin
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(w);
        AContext.Connection.IOHandler.WriteLn(h);
        // Then add the same for Pixels
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different ways to do this, so it's not possible to say exactly what you *should* do. For example if you look at the HTTP protocol it sends headers and data, the headers describe the data that is following. So the headers would say either how much data there is, or possibly how to determine how much data there is (like a chunked encoding). Other protocols (OSI X25 for example) send information in defined message with binary coded headers.

Designing a communications protocol can be challenging and also rewarding.

I would suggest you consider how many different types of data you want to send in each direction. Then consider that in the future you may want to send more.

You may want to have an application communicate with multiple clients at the same time, so think about how you identify each 'session' to the other side. For each message received you want to be able to determine what the data is first, then process it. You could use a text based header (easier to debug) like HTTP, or you could go for a defined structure with predefined values transferred as binary data (more compact).

I would typically expect that each message received would have a header containing:

Session ID (allowing one program to service multiple connections)
Data Type
Data-Type dependent information (variable number of data items according to the type)
Content Length

This would be followed by the content.  You can keep the content and the headers in one message, and try to keep the messages fairly short.

You may find it easier to break up the screenshot into defined parts.  This also means that if you compare the current screenshot to the last one you would only need to send changes to the screen layout. So when you send a part you need to give both the size of the part you are sending and its position.

Once you have something basic working you can extend it in all sorts of ways if you have designed a flexible protocol for the information exchange.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, basically what i want to achieve is a simple screen sharing application which i can use at work, say i want to have to work on some project in the office and i am on leave for instance, i can run the application on the main server , go home and control the PC right from my house . thats what screensharing application which basically uses the RFB (Remote frame buffer) protocol to share screen, thats all.

Comment: @Roy - OK, then you need to implement the RFB protocol. Your question did not mention that specifically. Look at the protocol definition and then write code that implements it. I interpreted your question as being a general coding question about implementing a communications protocol.

Comment: thats what i meant, so i was asking if i get the dimensions to be assigned by something like in the first source where i did something like dimensions := w * h / 4; or like the second example i later saw something online after a deep search https://codepad.co/snippet/delphi-small-vnc-server-using-indy-comps

Comment: so what i was thinking is , the server sends the width * height / 4 , reciever gets it (recv) and shows in Picturebox, hope i am not missing anything here

Comment: RFB has an RFC and there are lots of implementations available. This means you can test your versions against others to check they work as expected which is good news. If you haven't done any network programming before, a tool like Wireshark can be very helpful - it will allow you to see information that's exchanged and if you hit problems you can compare what you have done with what another implementation does. Good Luck!